# Help with probability question about duration of transistors

Tags: probability

I have the following problem (please help me, I am very bad at probability)
[image]

I know some equations can help me out...
$$f_X(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$$
$$F_X(x) = 1-e^{-\lambda x}$$
$$\mu = \frac{1}{\lambda}$$
The attempt to my solutions is the following

a) $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_X(x)f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{800} e^{-\frac{1}{800}x} \frac{1}{1000}e^{-\frac{1}{1000}y}$$
$$=\frac{1}{800000}e^{-\left(\frac{1}{800}x+\frac{1}{1000}y\right)}$$
$$F_{X,Y}(x,y) = F_X(x)F_Y(y)=(1-e^{-\frac{1}{800}x})(1-e^{-\frac{1}{1000}y})$$
$$F_{X,Y}(1000,1000) = (1-e^{-\frac{1000}{800}})(1-e^{-\frac{1000}{1000}})=0.451$$

b) I am having trouble with this: I know for sure that the first transistor will burn during the 800 hours pass, so the probability that it will burn before 1000 hours has passed is 1, but I don't know when this will happen, so I don't know what probability I have to calculate for the second transistor.
c) Apply the same concept of a) and get:
$$F_{X,Y}(1000,1000,1000) = (1-e^{-\frac{1000}{800}})(1-e^{-\frac{1000}{1000}})(1-e^{-\frac{1000}{500}})=0.389$$
d) I am also struggling with this
$$P(\text{won't fail in the next 1000 hours}|\text{didn't fail in the first 1000 hours})$$
$$=\frac{P(\text{won't fail in the next 1000 hours and didn't fail in the first 1000 hours})}{P(\text{didn't fail the first 1000 hours})}$$
$$=\frac{P(\text{won't fail in the next 1000 hours and didn't fail in the first 1000 hours})}{1-F_X(1000,1000,1000)}$$
$$=\frac{P(\text{won't fail in the next 1000 hours and didn't fail in the first 1000 hours})}{0.61}$$
I am having trouble of finding the probability of the numerator... Is it $$(1-F_X(1000,1000,1000))^2$$?

Comment: (a) Method and answer seem OK. You're dealing with the maximum. Your notation seems a bit off.  (b) If $X \sim \mathsf{Exp}(\mu = 800)$ and independently $Y \sim \mathsf{Exp}(\mu = 800)$, then $X+Y$ has a gamma distribution with shape parameter $2.$ (d) Use the no-memory property of the exponential distribution.

Comment: I get now part (b) but in (d) then $1-P(X>s) = 1 - P(X>s+t|X>t) = 1-\frac{P(X>2000)}{P(X>1000)}$. Is this okay?

Comment: @math4everyone No: argue why $\therefore\quad\mathsf P(\bigcap\limits_{i=1}^3\{X_i> 2000\}\mid \bigcap\limits_{i=1}^3 \{X_i>1000\}) ~=~ \prod\limits_{i=1}^3 \mathsf P(\{X_i> 1000\})$